# how to load a script after fullpage.js has finished

Tags: fullpage.js

i am having trouble with a script and remember reading someone that there is a way of using fullpage.js to command a script to run after it has finished loading to avoid issues. Does anyone know how to implement this. please give complete example.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just check the [fullPage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js). You'll find more about the `afterRender` callback in it.

Comment: how would you use that to load a script tried lots but my jquery is not that great.

Comment: afterRender: var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "https://somescript.js";
  $("head").append(s);

Comment: something like that?

Comment: Just read the docs regarding afterRender https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterrender